# How to connect to Oracle 11g using "Navicat for Oracle"?

Tags: oracle, network

My Oracle 11g Enterprise Manager runs like this:

[image]

I have taken the following screen-shot after my Oracle installation has been completed:

[image]

I have the following Oracle-related services running:

[image]

I am able to connect to Oracle 11g with SqlDeveloper like this:

[image]

But, this is not working:

[image]

It gives the following message:

[image]

Now, how to connect to Oracle 11g with Navicat?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change port 1158 to 1521 in your connection properties.

Oracle's listener for database connections runs on port 1521 by default.

Port 1158 is the web listener for Database Control, a webgui for managing the database.

In addition, the servicename should be something like "database.domain.com", or you can try using SID and specifying ORCL.

Answer (score 0):

check if Navicat is configured :
Tools/Options/Miscellaneous/OCI
see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcsBsvjVK4s

use the port from the installation and as ServiceName "XE":

Server Type: Oracle
Connection Name: Oracle 11g XE
Connection Type: Basic
Host Name/IP Address: localhost
Port: 1521
Service Name: XE
User Name: SYSTEM
Save Password: True

That worked for me :-)

Cheers!
Martin